# Get the number of UNIQUE facebook likes count for an URL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I've had an idea to make my website viral: a competition where the users make points and they win prizes. One of the ways they can get points is the following: if they share their personal page (they made on my website) on facebook they get 1 point for each like they get.

Then i made a PHP script which periodically queries facebook to ask the like_count the URL got. It simply queries for the `like_count` column in the `link_stat` table and then it evaluates the score.

**PROBLEM**

I've found a trick: if i share my personal page URL 100 times and then i like all the 100 links i shared (on facebook), `like_count` goes to 100. Which is bad for my competition, because as soon as someone finds this out, he will easily win the competition.

What i want to get, instead of `like_count`, is `the number of distinct people who liked that URL`.

This means, if i share the URL 100 times and i like it 100 times, my girlfriend likes it 30 times and my grandmother likes it 10 times, instead of 140 the count should be 3.

This way the competition would be perfectly regular.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check their Ip , or else normal facebook api do count per account

Comment: Ok. But how can i do it in FQL?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it with this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/ which says something like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM like WHERE object_id = ...
```

Basically it returns the people who liked certain object, which I assume would be 1 for you even if you like the same link 100 times?

Comment: Already tried! Doesn't work, because it returns the number of people who directly liked the URL by clicking like on the page itselft, not on the link to the page shared on facebook...